# С помощью чего и как сделать подобную анимацию сайта?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, анимация, vue.js, css-animation

[gif анимация примера](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mCenpWz50HZdz5nX5QTvQczzPD0w_u0E/view?usp=sharing)

В том числе интересно, возможно ли реализовать эту анимацию с помощь VueJS?

Comment: При чем здесь вуежс?

Comment: Можно. Использовать vuejs transition и css transition.

Comment: Вопрос никак не связан с вьюджиес.

Answer (score 1):

Во Vue есть встроенная компонента transition https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Вместе с этой компонентой может быть полезна библиотка animate.css https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Есть же Web Animations API

Comment: @lazyproger Есть, но во первых, есть беда с поддержкой - https://caniuse.com/#search=Web%20Animations%20API 


Во вторых - для анимации перехода лучше подходит css, т.к. браузер оптимизирует их.